# MySQL: Missing X Plugin

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

MySQL Version is 5.7.15. Ubuntu 16.04.1

I am trying to set up MySQL as a document store, as described in section 3.3 of the [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/document-store-setting-up.html)

When I run the command:

```
mysqlsh -u user -h localhost --classic --dba enableXProtocol
```

I get:

```
Creating a Classic Session to root@localhost:3306
Enter password:
No default schema selected.

enableXProtocol: Installing plugin mysqlx...
enableXProtocol: Error installing the X Plugin: Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysqlx.so' (errno: 2 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysqlx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

When I try:

```
mysql> INSTALL PLUGIN mysqlx SONAME 'mysqlx.so';
```

I get:

```
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysqlx.so' (errno: 2 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysqlx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

The manual says this plugin should be built in, but I can't find it when I run `SHOW PLUGINS()`.
I've searched Google and Stack Overflow, and found nothing regarding my issue.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL originally installed using `tasksel` as part of the LAMP stack.

Issue resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling MySQL through APT repository.

Answer (score 0):

I installed mysql by apt directly, and then has the same problem.

By chance I solved it by [download and upgrade MySQL APT repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) and then uninstalling and reinstalling MySQL.

In new repository, you can find it installs more applications:

mysql-community-client

mysql-community-server

..

So, i guess it just is community functions.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same question, because I want to use X dev api to connect Mysql. there is no mysqlx.so in the directory. I think it may be a bug.

Uninstall all things about mysql-server, and then follow the tutorial [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/), you`ll get it. In mysql 8.0, by default, mysqlx is ON.